# Recording application using template

Tags: jmeter

I have recorded my web application through template & just to confirm that load test result which i am getting is correct? Just by increasing No of users does it give proper results? Is it enough for load testing of web application?

Comment: go through the fundamentals of performance testing. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb924375.aspx. It depends on what is your SLA. Provide more details like you test plan, your requirements, expected behaviour, actual behaviour etc with screenshots

Answer (score 3):

First of all you need to ensure that your test does what it is supposed to be doing. Recorded tests can rarely be successfully replayed, so normally you should be acting as follows:

1. Add [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener and run your test with 1 user. Inspect request and response details to verify your test steps.
2. Perform correlation and parametrization if required.

   - Correlation: the process of identifying and handling any dynamic parameters. Most often people use [Regular Expression Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) for it.
   - Parametrization: the process of making your test data driven. For example, if your application assumes multiple authenticated users you need to store the credentials somewhere. Most commonly used test element for this is [CSV Data Set Config](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config)
3. Make your test realistic. Virtual users simulated by JMeter need to represent real users using real browsers as close as possible with all the related stuff: cookies, headers, cache, etc. See [How To Make JMeter Behave More Like A Real Browser](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733719-How-to-make-JMeter-behave-more-like-a-real-browser) to learn how to configure JMeter to act closer to real users. Also real users need some time to "think" between operations so make sure you are using [Timers](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#timers) to simulate this behaviour as well.
4. Only after you apply the above points you should add more virtual users. Again, run your test with 2-3 users and iterations to ensure your test funcitons as designed. Once you are happy with it you can increase the load, but don't overkill your server, increase the load gradually and check the impact of the increasing load on your application, i.e. how response time, throughput and number of errors change as you increase the load. The same is applicable for decreasing the load, don't turn it off at once, decrease the number of virtual users gradually.

   - [Building a Web Test Plan](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-web-test-plan.html)
   - [Building an Advanced Web Test Plan](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-adv-web-test-plan.html)